# VBA - Loops and WorkSheetFunction.vlookup gave partial and incorrect results?

Tags: excel, loops, vlookup

I have a workbook with multiple sheets.  Each sheet has 6 columns, column 1 has duplicate value.  I need to generate unique values from column 1 into column 9, then perform vlookup x to match with column 1 and if match with a specific value in column 2, then x = value in column 3.  Same tasks to result in y = value in column 6.  Then y-x = cells(1,9).  It should continue down the list.  Do all of above to all the sheets.

Following is my codes.  When I ran the codes, I have to run twice.  I got partial results in Sheet 1.  Then same value for each unique value in other sheets.  Please help.  Also, what would be a better way to do it? Thank you.

```
Sub UniquelistWorking()
Dim Ticker As String
Dim YearOpen As Double
Dim YearClose As Double
Dim PercentChange As Double
Dim TotalStockVolume As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim lastrowdata As Long
LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastrowdata = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
Dim myrange As Range
Set myrange = Range("A:G")
Dim i As Integer
On Error Resume Next

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    ws.Select

    Range("I1").Value = "Ticker"
    Range("J1").Value = "Yearly Change"
    Range("K1").Value = "Percent Change"
    Range("L1").Value = "Total Stock Volumn"

    ActiveSheet.Range("A2:A" & LastRow).AdvancedFilter , Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=ActiveSheet.Range("I2"), Unique:=True

    For i = 2 To lastrowdata

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 9), myrange, 2, False) = 20160101 Then

              YearOpen = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 9), myrange, 3, False)

        End If

        If Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 9), myrange, 2, False) = 20161230 Then

           YearClose = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Cells(i, 9), myrange, 6, False)

        End If

        Cells(i, 10).Value = YearClose - YearOpen
    Next i   
 Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: In your first VLookup function you are using the attribute "True" for the last value. Are you sure this isn't meant to be "False"? The reason i ask, is that a value of True finds an approximate matching value.

Another thing, are the date values actually stored as dates or as numbers? The reason i ask this, is that your date values could be subtracting from each other incorrectly as well.

Comment: Yes, it was false.  I did change that but didn't update it here.  The date value in Column 2 is number.

Comment: All of your dates should be stored as Dates! If you store them as numbers, then you will get REAL number results. (example: `20160420 - 20160515 = 95` Whereas date values give you this `2016/04/20" - 2016/05/15 = 25` Days)